# trying to get most recently modified csv in an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

here is my code.

```
import boto3

def get_most_recent_s3_object(bucket_name):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='br-candles')['Contents']
    #csvs = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs) if obj['Key'].endswith('.csv')][0]
    csvs = filter(lambda obj: obj['Key'].endswith('.csv'), objs)  # csv only

    paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='br-candles')
    for csv in csvs:
        for result in page_iterator:
            if "Contents" in result:
                latest = max(result['Contents'], key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
                return latest
                print(latest)
```

I have a single .csv in that bucket. Eventually, I will have multiple csv's in there and I want to get the most recently modified one. However, I am not getting any results back from this. The script finishes with exit code 0. So, no errors, but no results. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not even calling your `get_most_recent_s3_object` function. So obviously it will not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program starts by calling `list_objects_v2()` and filters the results into the `csvs` variable (but will only have a maximum of 1000 objects). Then, it begins a whole new call to `list_objects_v2()` via a paginator and iterates through the results for every CSV in the original call. This is somewhat convoluted.

Here is a revised version of your code:

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'

object_list = []

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET)

for result in page_iterator:
    object_list += filter(lambda obj: obj['Key'].endswith('.csv'), result['Contents'])

object_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])

print(object_list[-1]['Key'])
```

Alternatively, here is a version that uses an **S3 Resource** that is a bit easier since it handles all the pagination for you:

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'

object_list = []

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.all():
    key = object.key
    if key.endswith('.csv'):
        object_list.append((object.last_modified, key))

object_list.sort()
print(object_list[-1][1])
```

Comment: Thanks a million John. What if I wanted to also retrieve another value, which would be the most recently modified file from the prior day. I expect to drop multiple files per day there and I will want to be able to retrieve the last modified one from the prior day also. So, today_file = (object_list[-1][1]) would represent the most recent file for the current day, but something like yesterday_file = ??) would represent the last modified file from prior day.

Comment: `object_list[-1]` refers to the last element of a list that is sorted by date. So, it is actually returning "the object with the latest last_modified date" rather than "the most recent file for the current day". If you want to find yesterday's latest file it would simply involve Python manipulation of the data in the `object_list`. Be aware that `last_modified` is in UTC, so you'll need to be careful about how you define "prior day" -- it would require a bit of timezone manipulation.